# ASP.NET MVC how to populate a collection to a 4 column table?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a collection which I passed from my MVC controller to my view. In my view, I want to list the image and its description in a 4 column table. I did not use a grid.

So, If I get collection of 8, I will get a gallery list of 4 items in 2 rows of the table.

If I get 16, I will get 4 columns in 4 rows of the table.

In my code, I started off with add all the product items in one row. I need to add a new row after each set of 4 items.

How can I do that?

Is there a better control to use?

```
<table class="table-responsive">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var product in Model)
                    {

                        <td>

                            <img src=@product.Thumbnail style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 small">

                                @product.Title<br>
                                @product.Description<br>
                                @product.Audience<br>
                                @product.Company<br>
                                <label>Published : </label> @product.PubDate<br>
                                <label>Download : JPEG | PDF</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: That's how I would do it.  I'm sure there would be debate whether to use a <table> or <div> but in this case I think a <table> is also appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I gess the most elegant way to do it is use linq to group all your products by 4 and then generate your table:

1 row for each group and 1 column for each product:

```
<table class="table-responsive">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var productGroup in Model.Select((e, i) => new { Product = e, Grouping = (i / 4) }).GroupBy(e => e.Grouping))
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var product in productGroup.Select(x => x.Product))
                {
                    <td>
                        <img src=@product.Thumbnail style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 small">
                            @product.Title<br>
                            @product.Description<br>
                            @product.Audience<br>
                            @product.Company<br>
                            <label>Published : </label> @product.PubDate<br>
                            <label>Download : JPEG | PDF</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note `Grouping = (i / 4)` line. That's where you can change how many products you will have in a row.