# Razor table with two columns in mvc

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

this my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int PID = -1, int TID = -1, string DateT = "")
        {
            return View(barcodes);
        }
```

in my view :

```
@model IEnumerable<barkod.Models.Barcode>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.barC)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
```

It is okay, but I want the table information to be in two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the table tag around your foreach loop. If you want to have 4 columns you have to add a counter. Either use a for loop instead of foreach (depending on your model type) or add your own row counter.

```
@model IEnumerable<barkod.Models.Barcode>

@{ int counter = 0; }

<table>
    <tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.barC)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        @if (++counter % 2 == 0)
        {
            </tr><tr>
        }
    }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Like this on every 2nd loop a new row is added. You will have to add some additional logic to handle the case when the number of items is not equal.

Comment: it's true
  But
My question was not

Comment: @mohammadmiraali what is your question? You have two columns in your table, do you want 4? Maybe you could use CSS to create a 4 col layout

Comment: how to put each 2 item in one tr with foreach ?

Comment: @mohammadmiraali I edited my answer. Here might be another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454686/asp-net-mvc-how-to-populate-a-collection-to-a-4-column-table